# Instagram crawler without using Instagram API?

Tags: api, instagram

Is this possible?

The reason for asking is that the 2016 update with the Instagram API creates a sandbox and live environment. The sandbox is of limited value since you only get to use data of those users within the sandbox. If you get denied for the live upgrade, your existing application was wasted in effort.

I would like to identify a second possibility (such as HTTP?). Anything exists?

Comment: explain what u r trying to do ?

Comment: i would like to examine the popular of certain business based on the number of likes and unique postings and see if the values trend different over time

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a valid use case for brands/businesses, complete the app make it look professional and get reviewed for `public_content` permission, submit a video of app.
No other way to get around, just follow the guidelines and get app approved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with Selenium and Proxies